# Disable scrolling only for the first row of the dynamic table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In a dynamic table view, I have two different prototypes, I just want the the first prototype remind constant and scrolling with entire table view and the second prototypes should be scrolling. To be more clear, the first prototype will be created once, that is why I want to have it all the time in the first row, but the second prototype will be created unlimitedly, so they have to be scrolling. 
Is it possible in dynamic `UITableView`?
Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a custom view for the first part, place it just above your `tableView` then use your prototype cell for the entire table.

Comment: Is it possible when I use UITableViewController?

Comment: I don't think so, use `UIViewController` instead for more usability and flexibility.